# How can I fix If NO MATCH #N/A?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a schedule table to pull the corresponding working hours for each shift that match.

I have the following data:

CELL 1: E694

CELL 2: E356

TABLE 1: $AL$10:$AL$16

TABLE 2: $AL$1031:$AL$1037

TABLE 3: $AM$1031:$AM$1037

Here's the intended scenario:

If CELL 1 MATCH TABLE 1, then MATCH CELL 2 with TABLE 2 and pull data from TABLE 3.
If CELL 1 DON'T MATCH TABLE 1, MATCH CELL 1 with TABLE 2 and pull data from TABLE 3.

I tried the following formula:

`=IF(MATCH(E694,$AL$10:$AL$16,0), timevalue(INDEX($AM$1031:$AM$1037,MATCH(E356,$AL$1031:$AL$1037,0),0))*24, timevalue(INDEX($AM$1031:$AM$1037,MATCH(E694,$AL$1031:$AL$1037,0),0))*24)`

The formula only works when there's a MATCH, but If there's no MATCH it doesn't execute the false condition and returns #N/A error.

I know I'm missing something here, but I just can't figure it out.

Would someone be able to give me a hand here?

P.S: here's a simple test sheet (not with the exact same values, but the same formula and logic)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wvw-K7iZ6TnID-SzLt2CtOxu4Xx1BuhAjexU_onRASg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a test sheet.

Comment: I've added a test sheet. Please check

Comment: Where is Table 1? Currently your formula has a logic error in it, and a missing table could very well be the reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ISNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093293) is most likely what you are wanting, though `ISERR` or `ISERROR` could also be applicable depending on the situation.

A couple notes:

- I duplicated your original sheet ([see the "Fixes" tab on your Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wvw-K7iZ6TnID-SzLt2CtOxu4Xx1BuhAjexU_onRASg/edit#gid=2108153707)), and tightened up the layout slightly so I could better understand what you're trying to accomplish.
- I'm using named ranges in your formula for the tables now, instead of absolute A1 notation ranges. They are easier to maintain, less error prone, and less confusion when writing formulas.
- I removed the `timevalue(...) * 24` you were using to convert the formatted DateTime strings to TimeSpans. Instead, I set that column format to TimeSpan (`h:mm`), which does exactly the same thing without cluttering our formulas.
- "Formula", "Cell 1", and "Cell 2" I separated into columns, so that you and I could test and verify the formula on multiple variations of the cell values at once. The 8 rows you see now are 8 variations of cell 1 and cell 2 ("Formula" column is the same same for all test rows).

The updated working formula is below, based on *my best interpretation* of your description.

```
=IF(
COUNTIF(table1, B1), 
INDEX(table3, MATCH(C1, table2, 0)), 
INDEX(table3, MATCH(B1, table2, 0)))
```

As seen in the help popup in the image below, an `IF` statement evaluates the first argument (`logical_expresion`), which *must* be a value that can be converted into a boolean value (true/false).

Since numbers can represent a bool value (0 = false, anything else = true), and all we need for the first argument is a yes/no, I replaced the first `MATCH` function with a simple `COUNTIF`, which simply returns the number of cells in `table1` that match `B1`. Unlike the `MATCH` function, which returns `N/A` if no matches are found, `COUNTIF` simply returns a 0. Since 0 is the same as false, our `IF` statement knows to use our second `MATCH` instead of the first.

[image]

*Note regarding my original answer:* The first solution I provided used `ISNA(MATCH(...)) = false` instead of `COUNTIF(...)`. This works also, but is unnecessarily complicated: `ISNA` returns true if the value of it's argument is "N/A", true otherwise, effectively converting our `MATCH` into a bool value. That bool value had to be inverted, however, so that "N/A" value would be false, and a successful match would be true. `=false` was just used to return the opposite value that `ISNA` gave us. Does false=false? yes, so we return true. Does true=false? no, so we return...false.

Comment: This formula works one way. Check the sheet, I changed the value of CELL 1 to match TABLE 2 and it broke the formula.
The thing, is it must take into consideration both cases.

Comment: That error is there for a reason; it's a logic error, and it's **not** a bug in this case. It's occurring because your `else` condition changes search keys when it branches, and is executing the second match lookup on cell 2's value, not cell 1's. Since cell 2 contains the same value that cell 1 failed on, your second match must fail also. You're pulling a Kansas City Shuffle on yourself.

Comment: Man, I really appreciate your time and dedication in providing such a high-quality answer. I'm still not an expert in GSheets, so I need time to understand the logic of the twist you made with that ISNA & =false, but the formula works just fine! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @WaelEl glad it helped. I provided an explanation of my `ISNA(...) = false` logic at the end of my answer. I also updated the formula in my answer to use the more appropriate `COUNTIF` function since that avoids the need to handle error cases (`ISNA`), requires no conversions (`=false`), and better expresses the intent in the code. The Google Sheet has been updated with the new formula also.